# Angular 12 *ngFor Displays Parent Menus but don't display subsequent child menus from Nested Array

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

**Here is my Nested Array result from typescript.ts**

```
[
    {
        "0": {
            "menuName": "Home",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "subMenuName": "",
                    "subMenuValue": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "2": {
            "menuName": "User",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "subMenuName": "User List",
                    "subMenuValue": "/users"
                }
            ]
        },
        "5": {
            "menuName": "ABC",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "subMenuName": "ABC Admin menu 1",
                    "subMenuValue": "/DEF/DEFreport"
                },
                {
                    "subMenuName": "Fund ",
                    "subMenuValue": "/admin/manage-sub-fund"
                },
                {
                    "subMenuName": "ABC Screen",
                    "subMenuValue": "/admin/ABC"
                }
            ]
        },
        "6": {
            "menuName": "AI",
            "childs": [
                {`enter code here`
                    "subMenuName": "AI Screen",
                    "subMenuValue": "/AI"
                }
            ]
        },
        "8": {
            "menuName": "DEF",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "subMenuName": "DEF Int List",
                    "subMenuValue": "/admin/DEFreport-Intdist"
                },
                {
                    "subMenuName": "DEF Ext List",
                    "subMenuValue": "/admin/DEFreport-Extdist"
                },
                {
                    "subMenuName": "DEF ISIN",
                    "subMenuValue": "/admin/DEFassign"
                },
                {
                    "subMenuName": "DEF Report",
                    "subMenuValue": "/DEF/DEFreport"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**This is how I am trying to access in component.html page**

```
<div *ngFor="let parent of results[0] | keyvalue" style="color: antiquewhite;" class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
            style="color: antiquewhite;">{{parent.key}}</button>
 
            <div *ngFor="let child of parent.childs" class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="{{child.subMenuValue}}"
                    routerLinkActive="active">{{child.subMenuName}}</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to display dynamic menus from database.
Please Correct me as, I am new to angular.
It might be possible, I am writing wrong parent and child menus properties names.
any help regarding solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `*ngFor` directive allows iterating over a collection, and what you posted is NOT an array (as you seem to describe it), and hence is not a collection. It's an object, which is something different in javascript.

You can use the angular's built-in [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe), which transforms an object into an array of key-value pairs, to iterate the properties of the object though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the help of keyvalue like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let parent of results[0] | keyvalue" style="color: antiquewhite;" class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
            style="color: antiquewhite;"> {{parent.value["menuName"]}}</button>

  <div *ngFor="let child of parent.value['childs']" class="dropdown-menu">
    {{child.subMenuName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found few problems with KeyValuePipe, for the child sub menus parents are being displayed i did changes on my object to become flat array and basis on this i have implemented changes on the HTML to loop through menus and sub-menus. which resolved the issue.